# Does FIFA 15 contain the momentum feature?

Tags: fifa-15

The so called "momentum" (or scripting/handicap) feature changes the abilities of the players on the pitch from game to game in a seemingly random manner, usually giving one of the teams a major advantage, while the other has an increased chance of failed passes or hitting the post.

It was heavily featured in FIFA 13 and FIFA 14, which lead to a lot of discussion and is dreaded by many players, but EA apparently wants to keep it in to make matches more unique and give weaker players a better chance for winning once in a while against stronger opponents.

Obviously this is a bad idea for online play, especially competitive play in leagues etc.

**Is there any official information if momentum is included in FIFA 15 for online modes like Seasons?**

The problem with simply checking it by playing is that you usually have to play a lot of matches to be able to tell that momentum exists (and you are not simply having a bit of bad luck).

Comment: I really hope we can get a definitive answer on this,  although I'm almost certain that match-fixing is here to stay. I'm holding off on buying this version until I hear some kind of feedback indicating that this behavior has at least been reduced. EA has made this once great title utterly unplayable!

Answer (score 1):

Yup it exists. Exactly the same as Fifa 14 from my experience so far. Opponents outrun my defenders who can't seem to move and score from improbable angles whereas Bale shoots wide on a one on one with the keeper. Last night's stats had me with 17 shots of which 13 were on target. The opponent had 4 shots with 2 on target. I lost 2-0.

Answer (score 0):

It definatly exists i was lucky with packs so i got 2 teams worth 2.7mill between them with hazard,augero,toure,suarez,bale and neymar if when i win i win well as iam a good player on fifa 15 and if i go on a run of 4 games winning it turns my players into zombies who cant hit a barn door or string passes together for 2 or 3 games against people you can see are not as good as you at the game, you absolutly hammer them having 20odd shots they have 2 and beat you 2 nil